# About Navigation Breadcrumb Blogspot...?

Tags: website-design, forms, web-app, breadcrumbs, seo

How important are breadcrumbs? I understand it is important for navigation but I'm not certain how important it is for SEO? Are there use cases where breadcrumbs do not help SEO - and therefore is not worth the time to set up and maintain?

Comment: At least for me it is not really clear what you are asking. Please try to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about SEO and not UX.

Answer (score 1):

### First and foremost:

You should think about satisfying the needs of your users. No SEO argument should stand in the way of providing them with the tools they need.

With that in mind:

Breadcrumbs do highlight important keywords for search engines but most importantly they act as secondary navigation and help users know where they are within a website structure. Below is a quick **list of benefits to your users**:

> - Breadcrumbs show people their current location relative to higher-level concepts, helping them understand where they are in
>     relation to the rest of the site.
> - Breadcrumbs afford one-click access to higher site levels and thus rescue users who parachute into very specific but inappropriate
>     destinations through search or deep links.
> - Breadcrumbs never cause problems in user testing: people might overlook this small design element, but they never misinterpret
>     breadcrumb trails or have trouble operating them.
> - Breadcrumbs take up very little space on the page.
>
> Source: [Breadcrumb Navigation Increasingly Useful](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/breadcrumb-navigation-useful/)

So, to answer your question:

### Yes, it worth the time to set up and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the article I read which speak about this subject.
But anyway, It says (from a Google employee) that they will reward websites for the user experience comfort more than technical guidelines everybody's following. 
And I think giving everything to the user is better (in business terms) than SEO (word of mouth, satisfaction, retention)